# How to get and set Real value from RealEdit in a Form's Grid ?

Tags: forms, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have in a *Grid* a **RealEdit** , I set the *autodeclaration* YES.

The name is **myRealEdit** , *DataSource* is **myTable** and the *Field* is **myRealField**.

In the *modified* method I want to get the value, I need to do a *IF* control.

IF the value is 0 change the *Filed's value* IF the value is not 0 
throws the value entered and restores the previous value.

I used this code, in *modified* method:

```
public boolean modified()
{
boolean ret;
real storedValue;

ret = super();

storedValue = myTable.myRealField; // there is another way to get the value ? 

if (myRealEdit.valueStr() == "0")
//accept the value

if (!myRealEdit.valueStr() != "0")
{
myRealEdit.realValue(storedValue);
}

return ret;
}
```

If the value is not 0 (zero) don't restore the previous value.

I have to use another method ? There is another way to get the real value ?

Thanks in advice,

enjoy!!

Comment: On a higher level, what do you want to accomplish? 
As your code is totally broken, it is hard to deduct what you are trying.
May I guess: you will not accept zero as a value. Have you considered the the `Mandatory` attribute on the table field, datasource field or control?

Comment: Thanks @JanB.Kjeldsen for your comment.
I want to accept only 0 value , in another case I set again the value with previous value.

For example : I have stored value 50 , if I put the value 80 , I dont'accept this value and restore 50 in _myRealEdit_

Comment: But I don't know well how to get the realValue from _myRealEdit_

Comment: Your `myRealEdit` should be a bound control. Then you won't have to any code in the control, do it in the `validateField` of the table.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen  I just want not to allow entry of non-zero values by form (
only from that form, I do not want to create a general rule), thanks for your time.

Comment: Then use `validateField` from the form datasource: `if (!t.x) t.x = t.orig().x`

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen many tips.
Do you know a way to get the value inserted in _myRealEdit_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `modified` method in your answer, I suppose you want to put this field validation on the control level (instead of the datasource or table level).

As @Jan B. Kjeldsen suggested in his comment, you should use the `validate` method to do this validation. Use the `modified` method only if you want to add some logic that is executed in addition to the field value modification.

The `validate` method could look similar to

```
public boolean validate()
{
    return this.realValue() == 0 && super() || checkFailed(strFmt("Value %1 is not permitted", this.realValue())); 
    // TODO please replace this with a Label and explain to the user why the value is not permitted and what he or she can do to resolve this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a possible way,

I used this code:

```
public boolean modified()
{
 boolean ret;

 if (myRealEdit.valueStr() == "0")
 {
 //accept the value
     ret = super();
 }
 if (!myRealEdit.valueStr() != "0")
 {
  info("Value not permit");
  // nothing to do
 }
 return ret;
 }
```

In this way, if and only if I have a value 0 I modified the value.

I need to get or read the Real value just inserted from **myRealEdit** in the modified method.

If the community has comments or improvements inserted, will be more information.

Comment: Like Jan B. Kjeldsen suggested, use the `validateField` method instead, if this method returns `false`, the field will be automatically reset to its former value.

Additionally, do not use `valueStr()` to get the value of the real control. Use `realValue()` instead and compare it with a real value.

Also, the expression `if (!myRealEdit.valueStr() != "0")` does not do what you describe (I am confused why it even compiles for you, I get an operand types compile error because a boolean value cannot be compared to a string).

Comment: Testing on `valueStr()` instead of `realValue()` feels wrong.